# Is there a base Zend class that can be used to eliminate conventions boilerplate code?

Tags: zend-framework

One of the patterns that I've noticed in the Zend Framework classes is code very similar to the following. It can been in some 20-30 files.

```
public function __construct($options = null)
{
    if (is_array($options)) {
        $this->setOptions($options);
    } elseif ($options instanceof Zend_Config) {
        $this->setConfig($options);
    }

    // do custom initialization
    $this->_init();
}

public function setOptions(array $options)
{
    foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
        $this->set($key, $value);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function set($property, $value)
{
    if (!is_string($property) || empty($property)) {
        require_once 'Zend/Navigation/Exception.php';
        throw new Exception('Invalid argument: $property must be a non-empty string');
    }

    $method = 'set' . self::_normalizePropertyName($property);

    if ($method != 'setOptions' && $method != 'setConfig' &&
        method_exists($this, $method)) {
        $this->$method($value);
    } else {
        $this->_properties[$property] = $value;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

When I develop my own classes, I also put in similar boiler plate code. Is there a Zend Framework class that already has this minimal boiler plate code that I could extend instead?

If not, why isn't there one? Would it not help to keep the code DRY and consistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a ZF contributor but I believe the answer is simply that this has evolved over time into a convention as components have been added to the framework. ZF2 (currently in beta) does address this with a standard Options class that other components can extend - see https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/4f3c989efd04f07c78415192b0dee3c867e02199/library/Zend/Stdlib/Options.php

In the short term, if you find yourself needing something similar why not create a class like this that your own classes can extend.

Comment: Good point, just thought I'd mention to the flammon that I usually have a base class for models, and mappers that all models/mappers in my application extend from.  They contain many of those utility functions as well as other code you may frequently find yourself needing.

Comment: I've developed my own base classes but was hoping to get one that came with ZF1 and could not find it. Now I'm even more anxious to get going with ZF2. Thanks.